# Add node to a tree in c

Tags: c, tree, addition

What's the problem with this function (the processus stop working)

```
void ajout_el(Tree **head,int key) {
if(!(*head)) {
   (*head)->key=key;
   (*head)->left=(*head)->right=NULL;
}
else {
    if(key>(*head)->key) ajout_el(&(*head)->right,key);
    else ajout_el(&(*head)->left,key);
}}
```

Here's the main function

```
int main() {
Tree *arb=NULL;
int i;
for(i=1;i<=10;i++) ajout_el(&arb,i);
return 0;}
```

Comment: Is there an error message?

Comment: No, the process just stop working

Comment: I suggest you run your process in valgrind, it will help you find which line triggers the segmentation fault.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The immediate problem is that the very first insert will dereference a `NULL` pointer:

```
if(!(*head)) {
   (*head)->key=key; /* (*head) is guaranteed to be NULL here - you've just checked! */
   (*head)->left=(*head)->right=NULL;
}
```

You need to allocate some memory for `*head`. See [`man malloc`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc).

Once you've started allocating memory, you'll need to think about how you're going to free it to avoid [memory leaks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak). A recursive function for deleting a tree would be a good way to start.

For future reference, a good way to troubleshoot problems like this is by running the program in a debugger. The debugger would show the exact line of the crash and would enable you to examine the state of the program at the point of the crash. This often makes it much easier to see what's going wrong.

Comment: Fixed, just added (*head)=(Tree *)malloc(sizeof(Tree));
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to allocate memory for new node. There should be

```
void ajout_el( Tree **head, int key ) 
{
    if( !*head ) 
    {
        *head = malloc( sizeof( Tree ) )
        ( *head )->key = key;
        ( *head )->left = ( *head )->right = NULL;
    }
    else 
    {
        if( key > ( *head )->key ) ajout_el( &( *head )->right, key );
        else ajout_el( &( *head )->left, key );
    }
}
```

The same way could look the function that frees all allocated memory. For example

```
void FreeTree( Tree *head ) 
{
    if ( head ) 
    {
        if ( head->left )  FreeTree( head->left );
        if ( head->right ) FreeTree( head->right );
        free( head );
    }
}
```

Or

```
void FreeTree( Tree **head ) 
{
    if ( *head ) 
    {
        if ( ( *head )->left )  FreeTree( &( *head )->left );
        if ( ( *head )->right ) FreeTree( &( *head )->right );
        free( *head );
        *head = NULL;
    }
}
```